# Custom select in jQuery

Tags: jquery

on my site i want to do a custom select. On click i want to slideDown a div, which have some filters. Structure:

```
<div class="select" style="position:relative;height:20px;">
   <span class="label">somelabel</span>
   <div style="display:none;position:absolute;top:20px;left:0;" class="select_inner">
      <label for="something">
         <input type="text" name="something">
      </label>
      <label for="something">
         <input type="text" name="something">
      </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Div with class select_inner is hidden, i want to show it when somebody click on span width class label. And hide when somebody click on everything else except div with class select_inner. And thats the problem... I try something like this:

```
$('.select').click(function(){
   var select = $('.select_inner', this);
   select.slideDown();
   $(this).parents().click(function(){
      select.slideUp();
   });
});
```

And it works but wrong. When i click on my div, child div slides down and instantly up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('.select').click(function(event){
event.stopPropagation();
var select = $('.select_inner', this);
select.slideDown();

});

$('html').click(function() {
 var select = $('.select_inner', this);
 select.slideUp();
});
```

​
​
See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A6ZNY/). The way it works is that on any click outside of the `select` div, it attempts to slide up the `div`, but if you click on the `select` div, it will stop the event and do a `slideDown` instead.

**EDIT**

I made a mistake in the initial script. I updated the script above to fix the problem. See the updated fiddle in IE and Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/A6ZNY/1/

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to mark it as the correct answer by selecting the tick mark next to the answer.

Comment: See the updated script. I forgot to pass in the `event` in the function. This one will work in IE and Firefox

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.select span.label').click(function(){
    $('.select_inner').slideToggle("fast");
});
```